# lxterminal not working

Tags: 11.10, command-line, lubuntu

My Lxterminal is not working.

Here's some background:

A few days ago I wanted to configure the keyboard layouts for my Lubuntu 11.10 for English and Romanian. You can find a detailed description of what I did [here:](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11793260)

So, it worked for a few days. Today it stopped working again. So I started reading forums again. I tried to follow [this forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102344/switching-keyboard-layouts-in-lubuntu-11-10). So I went up in the terminal, went into the .bashrc file and added this

```
sudo tee -a /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

right after this:

```
setxkbmap -layout "us,ro(winkeys)" -option "grp:ctrl_shift_toggle"
```

Then pressed Ctrl+X and Enter.

Almost at the same time I installed some system updates.

A few minutes later I wanted to use the terminal again, and I noticed that the terminal no longer starts with the line user@user-pc:-$. Instead, it jumps straight to this:

```
[sudo] password for dora:
```

I type in the password but nothing happens. Also, whatever other command I try to type, it just gets returned. No errors messages, nothing.

Please help.

PS: Funnily, I just noticed that I am now able to type in Romanian again!

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up:

Just found a thread with the same problem. Apparently the terminal behaves like that due to the fact that I typed a sudo command inside the .bashrc, and now it tries to execute it every time I open the terminal.

I placed a # in front of that sudo command like this:
    #sudo tee -a /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
And decided I'd leave it there suspended, just in case. De-activating it like this restored my terminal to normal.

I've had occasional problems of the keyboard layout switch not working. In those cases it seems that simply opening and closing the .bashrc file does the trick - I have no idea why. But it works.

I've opened and closed my .bashrc, and now it works.