# Why does Lubuntu not respect my keyboard preferences?

Tags: lubuntu, system-installation, keyboard-layout

I’ve just installed Lubuntu 14.04 on my laptop (replacing the previous dual boot Ubuntu 13.10 / Windows 7, which my poor little laptop really didn’t have the space for). As part of the installation process, I was asked to select my keyboard layout. I selected Irish, and double-checked that the problematic keys (", @, €) worked correctly. Everything seemed fine.

Now that the installation is complete, however, I have a US keyboard with no obvious way to change it (and no obvious way to type the € symbol). I am, of course, interested in fixing this, but I’d also like to know *why* this happened in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [switching keyboard layouts in lubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102344/switching-keyboard-layouts-in-lubuntu-11-10?rq=1).  I don't know why it didn't persist the keyboard you selected during the installation, however it might have something to do with the fact that the installer was designed primarily for the Unity desktop, and the keyboard settings are in a different location in Lubuntu, which is based on the underlying Openbox desktop

Comment: Looks like the problem may have been that the installer offers me a keyboard layout option which Lubuntu doesn't actually have! I've now selected a UK layout, and it seems to be working. (If my guess is correct, this is a bug. I may wander over to Launchpad and report it.)

Comment: Yes, so it is due to the difference in default available keyboards between the Unity and LXDE (openbox) desktops.  Ideally the installer should filter the options based on which desktop version you are installing (or even tweak the default keyboards to support the one you chose, one can only dream...) so it is not misleading like that.

Comment: FWIW the same happened to me with Lubuntu 15.04. I chose "Belgian (Wang)" during install, and got a US layout after reboot into the newly installed system. Thanks for the clarification (at least I know it's not just pure magic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the Keyboard Layout Handler icon in your LXPanel.  Choose Keyboard Layout Handler settings.  Untick Keep system layouts and then click add.  Choose Irish which I believe will show up as ie.  You can then move it to the top to have it be the default or keep it where it is and just toggle when you need it.  Check Keep system layouts.  I believe that it will not take effect until the next boot.